# Issue creating comments on object when object retrieved with first_or_create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Apologies in advance, rails newbie.

A landlord has N comments, a comment has 1 landlord

Question :  Why am I not creating a comment ? (returning a nil object)

In landlords_controller#create:
Creating the landlord or finding one if the credentials are already in the database :

```
@landlord = Landlord.where(:name => params[:landlord][:name],
:city => params[:landlord][:city], :province => params[:landlord][:province]).first_or_create!
```

when I call `@landlord.comments[0].setIP request.remote_ip`  afterwards

I receive error `undefined method setIP for nil:NilClass`

Providing the new and create methods in landlords controller

```
def new
  @landlord = Landlord.new
  @landlord.comments.build
end

def create      
#check if a landlord of the same name already exists and add comments to that db entry
@landlord = Landlord.where(:name => params[:landlord][:name], :city =>       params[:landlord][:city], :province => params[:landlord][:province]).first_or_create!
    #:comment =>  params[:landlord][:comments_attributes]
    @landlord.comments[0].setIP request.remote_ip

    if @landlord.save     

     redirect_to landlords_path
    else

end
```

end

comments controller is empty, I'm not positive if this is an issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 @landlord.comments.create if @landlord.comments.empty? #add this step
 @landlord.comments[0].setIP request.remote_ip
```

this is due to when first time you create i.e. when no landlord object is present, first_or_create! will create landload object without any comment.

Comment: Eliminated the nil:NilClass